# Can I access Lombok getters and setters annotated inside a dependency project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, lombok

I have a project 'Onboarding' which has another project 'EntityModel' as a dependency. Inside 'EntityModel' have a lot of entities annotated with Lombok, for example:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_generator_sequence")
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private long id;
(...)
```

but when I try to access the getters or setters of those entities in a 'Onboarding' class:

```
@PostMapping("/createCustomer")
public ResponseEntity<Customer> createCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) throws URISyntaxException {

        Address ad = new Address();

        ad.getId();

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/user/")).build();
    }
```

The IDE doesn't show up the getters in the options box, and when I run the build, the compller shows me this:

```
(...)/Restaurant/onboarding/src/main/java/com/restaurant/onboarding/controller/OnboardingController.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        ad.getId();
          ^
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: variable ad of type Address
```

when I opened the .class and realized the annotations didn't persist, I searched a little bit and saw that Lombok has the Retention as a Source. But even so, is there any other way, any other configuration that I can make to access Lombok getters and setters from another project?

Comment: Getters & Setters should be accessible also from different projects. If you're using IntelliJ - I encountered a lot of caching issues along the years, so make sure you `clean install`  the `EntityModel` project to make sure it's installed locally. Then, you might need to restart the IntelliJ instance of `Onboarding`

Comment: @idanz I already tried to open the same project and subprojects in eclipse and the same happens. I usualy use the Ubuntu terminal to run ./gradlew clean build, the error I snippeted in my question above was coppied from my Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: In your `Onboarding` project, do you have the `io.freefair.lombok` plugin configured in the plugins block? Or are you trying to get lombok working without the plugin?

Comment: Yes, I didn't have the io.freefair.lombok plugin configured, now that that I configured it's working, Thanks @SamYonnou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After configure the `io.freefair.lombok` plugin inside the 'Onboarding' build.gradle.kts, it works:

```
plugins {
java
war
id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
id("io.freefair.lombok") version "8.1.0"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use @Data annotation also inside the EntityModel file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I decided not to use Lombok @Data annotation because I'm using JPA and there's some articles on the internet warning about some problems that may occur when implementing these two thing together. like this one: [lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/)